# Swift UIView size incorrect

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, constraints

I've created a ViewController with a custom xib file. Insider I have a carefully placed view named `holderView` with the appropriate constraints:

[image: View With Constraints]

In the controller, i have the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    println(holderView.bounds)
    println(holderView.frame)
}
```

I get this values, instead of the real ones:

```
(0.0,0.0,320.0,568.0)
(0.0,0.0,320.0,568.0)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I've tried the exact same code and view inside a normal storyboard and it works ok. The viewController is loaded and attached by a `PageViewController`.

Comment: The correct values should be `(0,0,225.0,368.5)`

Comment: I noticed that using `view.layoutIfNeeded()` in the `viewDidLoad` fixes the problem. Is this the correct answer?

Comment: I don't know why you get the incorrect values. When I present a view controller with a xib view, I get the correct values in viewDidAppear. IS this xib controller the initial view controller of your app?

Comment: It's loaded from a PageViewController, which is the initial view controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Auto layout delays the time to draw the subview.  See if this works to get the view dimensions:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        println(self.holderView.frame.size)
    }
```

can use height, width, etc.

Comment: I just got a problem. How many times should `viewDidLayoutSubviews` be called? It was called for about 50 times and then the app crashed.

Comment: Neveermind, i was adding a view to a subview and this is why i got an infinite loop.

Comment: Can we rename viewDidAppear to viewDidntReallyAppearYet? :) I say that, because if it really did appear, we'd see the wrong frame, wouldn't we? Just joking, of course.